# Unable to find CUDA device in PyTorch on Debian 11

Tags: pytorch, debian, miniconda

OS: Debian 11
Miniconda 3
CUDA: 11.7

I get the following error when trying to start [text-generation-webui](https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui):

```
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly 
set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. 
Setting the available devices to be zero.
(Triggered internally at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1678411187366/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

And also at the end after traceback:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but
torch.cuda.is_available() is False. 
If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with
map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the source of the problem, but I found a workaround.

```bash
conda activate yourenv
python
```

```py
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.device_count()
```

It should display device count of one and then

```bash
python server.py --gptq-bits 4 --model llama-7b
```

(for example) will work as expected.